# Hover effects dont work

Tags: css

Hover effects don't work when I'm trying to make one element do something while hovering over another, as it is shown here:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>111</title>
<style type="text/css">
#aa {height: 500px; width:500px; background-color: blue; float: left;}
#bb {height: 500px; width:500px; background-color: red; float: left;}
#bb:hover #aa {background-color: green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="aa"></div>
<div id="bb"></div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Edit:
Sachin raises a very valid point. Did some testing and read around to confirm and http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject suggests that the selectors to do this are rediculously bleeding age :D

```
#bb:hover + #aa { } // Wont work
#aa:hover + #bb { } // Will work but within the scope of OPs question, useless.
```

Best solution would be to utilise JS and mouseover make the change.

Comment: did you try this? there is no previous sibling selector.

Answer (score 1):

Actually *there is no previous sibling selector*. So only this will work

```
#aa:hover + #bb   {background-color: green;}
```

But don't worry you can use JS or jQuery to solve this problem. Here is one simple solution using jQuery would be this

```
$('#bb').hover(function(){
    $(this).prev('#aa').css("background-color","green");
},function(){
    $(this).prev('#aa').css("background-color","blue");
});
```

Look at the demo which contains css sibling selector as well as jquery solution for selecting previous siblings.

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QRggv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As my previous answer was wrong and did not reaaly answer your question, i have updated my response.
I believe the best solution would be in JS similiar to Sachin suggestion. However just to not that in CSS3 there is a [General Sibling Selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector).

When using it in your case, we will be able to change a color of div #bb when hovering on div #a (not exactly as your example), i also agree with the others that for previous selector JS will be the way.

```
#aa:hover ~ #bb {
   color:red;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does it answer to OP's question? You have written separate styles for `bb:hover` and `aa:hover`. OP wants to change the style of one element on hover of another.

Comment: You are correct, didnt fully understand his question.

Comment: The ~ selector is so bleeding edge that I don't even think its supported by Chrome :(

Comment: Good to know. I tested it in FF, and it seemed to work